# iOS: Provision Profile from Environment Variable

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Is there any possibility to dynamically replace Provisioning Profile in XCode? Can environment variable help here or perhaps there can be added some configuration file, which will be used for signing?

For example I tried to hardcode custom profile variable
[image: Profile]

and assign needed value in current Scheme. But seems it doesn't work

[image: Environment Variables]

Are there any solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do by parameterizing the provisioning profile?  I don't believe you can use an environment variable, but you can pass in a provisioning profile if you do a build from the command line.  Also, you can have different provisioning profiles set up for your different build configurations, which would allow a single project to have multiple profiles (say one for debugging and another for ad hoc distribution).

Comment: Its very hard to explain why I need this. I do not want to create a build script with and run it from command line. It will not help in my case. What I need to make XCode recognize $MY_PROFILE variable somehow and launch the app on device.

Comment: So you have multiple provisioning profiles that maybe have different sets of devices in them.  Depending on the device, it will need to select a different profile? What drives the value in the environment variable? How would you expect that value to change?

Comment: Yes we have different profiles, but I actually do not really need them to change on my dev environment. $MY_Profile is used in Continuous Integration Server and it changes depending on its configuration. What I need is to stub this variable somehow, for example with empty string, so automatic profile will be selected by XCode and I will be able to compile the app on device.

Comment: I assume your CI server is a different machine than your development machine? If so, why not set your provisioning profile setting to automatic, and your signing identity to the generic iPhone Distribution.  Then, on the CI machine, only install the profile you want when building your CI builds.